# What is the most efficient way to count the number of instances of each unique vector in an array using Octave?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, octave

I need to identify the number of times each unique row vector occurs in a matrix.
Let's assume we have the following matrix:

```
A = [1  0  0, 
     1  0  1, 
     0  1  0,
     1  0  0,
     0  1  0]
```

By using the 'unique' function, we can identify the unique row vectors as:

```
U = [1  0  0, 
     1  0  1,
     0  1  0]
```

How can we then tabulate that both `[1  0  0] and [0  1  0]` occur twice in matrix A while `[1  0  1]` appears only once?
I have tried various applications of 'count' and 'sum' but they operate on the vector elements rather than the vector as a whole.  Thanks very much for your guidance on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Octave and MATLAB R2014a and earlier, you can use [`unique`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/unique.html) and [`hist`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/hist.html):

```
[U,~,c] = unique(A, 'rows');    %unique rows are given by 'a'
occ=hist(c);  occ=occ(occ~=0);  %number of occurrences of each row is given by 'occ'
```

If you have MATLAB R2014b or later, replace the last line that used depreciated [`hist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) with [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) (which is recommended) .

```
occ = histcounts(c);
```

or **the best/fastest of all**, as *[Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo)* suggested, you can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). [Octave's documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/accumarray.html) infact has a very similar example as that of your question.

```
occ = accumarray(c, 1);
```

Comment: Also `occ =accumarray(c, 1);` or `occ = sum(c==unique(c).', 1);` (I don't know which one is faster)

Comment: @LuisMendo checked it with  `timeit` for `A = randi([1 10],10000000,3);`   `histcounts` required 0.2040, `accumarray` took 0.1131` for me. 
couldn't check `sum` and `unique` due to the memory constraint. Yours solution with `accumarray` is better.

Comment: The following works perfectly. Thank you!                                                   
>> [U,~,c] = unique(A, 'rows');
>> occ = accumarray(c,1);